Is there a way to "merge" cells in a given row of a MUI DataGrid?
I've got a MUI DataGrid, and I'm going to force it to group by a particular property (in this case, the "section" of a list of questions). I'd like to render a custom view as the grouping-row - see in this screenshot how the "section" goes across the whole grid? I'm planning on putting more info across that section-header, like summary information, and I don't want the little table-cell boundaries slicing up the row.
Is that possible?

